# How to write a list comprehension without repeating the evaluation of a function?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

My apologies for this trivial question, but I cannot find a solution. I need to create the following list:

```
for i in x:
    if(f(i) < g(i)):
         my_list.append(f(i)*g(i))
```

but I don't know how to do it with the list comprehension without repeating the calculation of the functions `f()` and `g()`. I want to avoid it because they are computationally expensive. So I don't want something like:

```
[f(i)*g(i) for i in x if f(i) < g(i)]
```

because `f(i)` and `g(i)` are calculated twice at every iteration. I was wondering if there is a way to "store" somewhere the numbers `f(i)` and `g(i)` and to recall them inside the list comprehension.

Comment: um... very basic... what about variables to store the result of `g(i)` and `f(i)` ?

Comment: Well, I should also say that I don't want to use another for loop for creating a list that contains f(i) and g(i), bacause x is very big (therefore this solution would be very time consuming)

Comment: There's no need to create an extra list; see my answer. It's just that you don't *have* to throw away your intermediate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the values of the calls in a `for` loop target, if you create an iterable (like a tuple or a list) with just *one* element in it; that one element would be a tuple with the `(f(i), g(i))` result herer:

```
res = [fi * gi for i in x for fi, gi in [(f(i), g(i))] if fi < gi]
```

This is, however, *not pretty* and not very readable.

You'd be far better off using an actual `for` loop for this:

```
res = []
for i in x:
    fi, gi = f(i), g(i)
    if fi < gi:
        res.append(fi * gi)
```

Another option is to produce an intermediate generator expression that calculates `f(i)` and `g(i)`, then uses the output in a list comprehension:

```
intermediate = ((f(i), g(i)) for i in x)
res = [fi * gi for fi, gi in intermediate if fi < gi]
```

Comment: I think you have an extra one-element tuple in there.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree on the "not pretty" part.

Comment: @user2357112: there is exactly one element in the outer tuple, another tuple with the `f(i)` and `g(i)` results in it. The extra call parentheses do confuse things somewhat; a list is probably better.

Comment: No, wait, never mind. The tuple is fine. A list would probably be a bit more readable - but I see you just changed it to use a list.

Comment: Ok cool, so it seems that it's not possible to do it with just one `for`. Actually I forgot to say that I'd also like to avoid this because my variable `x` is very big, but it seems this is the only solution possible. I didn't think about the generator, I'll try your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

um... very basic... what about variables to store the result of `g(i)` and `f(i)` ?

instead of

```
for i in x:
    if(f(i) < g(i)):
         my_list.append(f(i)*g(i))
```

do something like

```
for i in x:
    a = f(i)
    b = g(i)
    if a < b:
         my_list.append(a*b)
```

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to write your last code in a list comprehension way?

Comment: yes, see martijn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40351410/4433386); but it's not intuitive to do. If you need an intermediate value again, save it to a variable. Period.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `append`, as follows:

```
def func(x):
    for i in x:
        a = f(i)
        b = g(i)
        if a < b:
            yield a*b

my_list = list(func(x))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try also this solution. Basically I'm trying to speed up my code, so `yield` could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
[ fi * gi for fi, gi in zip(map(f, x), map(g, x)) if fi < gi ]
```